# Are dropout layers equivalent to adding noise to training samples?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization, dropout

I'm doing reading around regularisation techniques for neural networks. My intuition is that dropout is essentially adding noise into the network by zeroing out activations according to a given probability.

Can the same result be achieved by introducing noise into training examples/layers given the same probability?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same in the sense that all regularization methods are *kind of* the same by forcing the model to be more robust. But as you can see, this is a quite vague statement. They are not the same in the sense that they would do it in a completely different way. Dropout [works by](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-dropout-method-work-in-deep-learning-And-why-is-it-claimed-to-be-an-effective-trick-to-improve-your-network) randomly turning off some of the parameters, so that the network needs to do the same job with fewer parameters. This forces it to build redundant, smaller sub-networks, and as a consequence forcing a simplified and more robust structure of the model. If you would add random noise to the input data, it wouldn't anyhow force changes in the structure of the model. It would force it to learn to deal with noisy data, but this does not necessarily need a simpler model or redundant structures.

If you want to visualize it, adding noise would mean that you add some random noise to the input (or output) layer nodes on the diagram below. Dropout would mean that at each epoch you would randomly remove some of the hidden layers nodes (circles) or connections between them (lines) or both, depending on the kind of dropout you are using. So dropout works on randomizing completely different things.

[image: Diagram showing regular neural networks.]

Comment: So does this mean that, in theory, these two methods could be used in conjunction with each other. The noise injection ensuring the network develops the ability to deal with noisy data (and I assume it would also stop it fitting to the noise already present in the data) and the dropout to help develop a more simplified and robust mapping function.

Comment: @Molem7b5 sure, as with any other regularization methods.